# Python best way to encrypt password in clear file

Tags: python, encryption, passwords

I am looking a way to get password from user but with a good security.

At the moment, I write user password in `yaml` file like that :

```
---
app:
  username: tata
  password: toto
```

with python's code :

```
 url = http://application.com
 username = Cfg.get(['app', 'username'])
 password = Cfg.get(['app', 'password'])
 auth = Appli(url, username, password)
```

but is's not very clean, I don't want to encrypt to `base64` with `base64` function.

Comment: If you consider base64 "encryption" you might as well write it in plain text... look up proper credentials mangement (that's mostly language-agnostic, btw) before focusing on how to implement that in python.

Comment: Passwords should be salted and hashed (with a slow hash function), not encrypted.

Comment: Consider looking into something like https://pypi.org/project/cryptography/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are lots of pythonic ways of doing it.
You can also store your password in the database level only in hash like `SHA1`, `md5`, `SHA256`, etc.

When a user types in his/her password, the system should convert it to hash (hash algorithm that you have selected) and then check it with that of the database if the entered password is correct or not.

```
import hashlib

url = http://application.com
username = Cfg.get(['app', 'username'])

password= Cfg.get(['app', 'password'])

#store pass_hash in the database
pass_hash= hashlib.sha256(password.encode()).hexdigest()

#authenticate using pass_hash not the actual textual password
auth = Appli(url, username, pass_hash)
```

In that case even if your database is exposed to somebody outside, your actual passwords will be safe, only the hashes will be visible.

Comment: i don't have a databse to store password

Comment: Its okay if you don't have a database as of now as long as you store and use the `pass_hash` for authentication not the `password`. Make sure you store the `pass_hash`s and `username`s associatively for now.

Answer (score 0):

Not really clear what problem you are trying to solve.

You can use [`pycrypto`](https://pypi.org/project/pycrypto/) to encrypt or decrypt your data, any modern algorithm will do. The real question is how you should store the key(s) if you need to access encrypted data programatically. Will storing encrypted data + key alongside really solve your security issues?

Side note: you may find [this old blog post](https://codahale.com/how-to-safely-store-a-password/) useful

Comment: yes, indeed, I am looking for a way to store key, salted and hashed may be a good way